# error in file field value display

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am using file field in my web page. I have to display default value for the file field. I used the following code.

```
<input name="" type="file" value="test" />
```

But it doesn't work. How can i do that?

Comment: That's not allowed. It isn't a textbox that you can just set a value on.

Comment: I set value for the file field. But it didn't display.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. File fields are locked down to prevent setting defaults as a security measure. If you could set default values, it'd be trivial to have

```
<input type="file" name="hackme" value="/etc/passwd" />
```

and steal arbitrary files from the client machines.

Comment: True. w3.org says "User agents may use the value of the value attribute as the initial file name"- I have given the link to in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The file input field cannot have a default value. Period. It's a security issue. Can't do it. Sorry.

---

After doing a little research, it appears they have modified the value attribute for file inputs in HTML 5:

> **input . value [ = value ]**
>
> Returns the current value of the form control.
>
> Can be set, to change the value.
>
> **Throws an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception if it is set to any value other than the empty string when the control is a file upload control.**

and

> **filename**
>
> On getting, it must return the string "C:\fakepath\" followed by the filename of the first file in the list of selected files, if any, or the empty string if the list is empty. **On setting, if the new value is the empty string, it must empty the list of selected files; otherwise, it must throw an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception.**

- [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value-filename)

So it appears W3C has gone with the "security issue" reasoning and changed its behavior in HTML5 anyways. I don't think you'll ever see the ability to predefine a value for a file input control.

Answer (score 1):

Although the HTML 4.01 specification says that “User agents may use the value of the value attribute as the initial file name,” it is just *may*, and browsers generally do not do that. Some past browsers had implementations that did so and possibly warned the user about the risks, but that was years ago.

The main security issue was that users would not notice the field at all (possibly because it is visually unnoticeable or hidden). But this was actually anticipated in the original design of file upload, RFC 1867. It said: “HTML interpreting agents are expected to confirm any default file names that might be suggested with `<INPUT TYPE=file VALUE="yyyy">`.” It seems that browser vendors just found it too complicated to implement well enough, considering the fairly limited usefulness of setting the default filename (as even filename syntax is platform dependent).

Answer (score 0):

w3.org says "User agents may use the value of the value attribute as the initial file name". But as far as I know, most browsers will not allow this as a securit measure. You can read about this here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1